# C# Start/Stop IIS Application pool programmatically with Access Denied issue

Tags: c#, iis, application-pool

I'm trying to simply start/stop the application pool in IIS programmatically in C# in the following code:

```
ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
ApplicationPoolCollection appPools = serverManager.ApplicationPools;
foreach (ApplicationPool ap in appPools)
{
            if (ap.Name == "Test App")
                ap.Start();
}
```

I already added the assembly Microsoft.Web.Administration in the project.
And I also gave the full permission for user "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" in the folder C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config. (Before giving this permission, it's not even able read the application pool name.)

However, it's still throw an exception when it's trying to start the application pool.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll
>
> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

What else permission should I need to add for fixing it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you download and run `procmon`? Just have it run with default settings, try your code, stop procmon (magnifying glass) and go to tools -> Count Occurrences ->  Column: Result -> Count. Double click ACCESS DENIED and draw conclussions from there.

Comment: Does it work elevated as administrator

Comment: I tried to run the procmon, and see there is Access Denied for the path C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config, however I still get the same issue after I gave the permission for the "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" in this folder

Comment: the program is already running in administrator

Comment: @Tak - Procmon also shows you what account is being used *(perhaps you have to add that column in the view)*. Can you verify it is the account you expect?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers yes it's using my current account that with admin permission. After I gave the permission in the path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\Config", now there are many ACCESS DENIEND for some RegCreateKey operations, such as "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\EnterpriseCertificates\Disallowed", "HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\Disallowed" that I no idea for it

Comment: Looks like you've opened a can of worms. I don't know nearly enough of the required security requirements but this starts to look like this is not the way to go about it ...

Comment: which IIS / OS are you using? can you set UAC to the lowest level for a try?

Comment: "the program is already running in administrator" is impossible. What kind of program? Console? Web app? Describe in which way you ran it as administrator, as you can simply get it wrong.

Comment: I am confused -- are you trying to stop/start an application pool from within an application pool?  Does the code work in a stand-alone C# console app running as administrator?

Comment: Sorry all for the late reply, my local machine is using Windows 10 with default IIS((Ver 10.0.14393.0). Basically I create an application in IIS Manager manually, then I just simply create a C# win form program with above code using Visual Studio and run the program in VS (and tried just click the .exe). I did all the task with my current account that have the administrator right in my local machine

Comment: Basically I just use my own account, I can start/stop the application pool in IIS Manager, that I just want to do the same thing in a simple C# win form program instead only. I believe it's very simple? I'm newbie in IIS I am not sure about the permission issue.

Comment: Is it possible IIS is not running? I've just found I get this exception when using the Stop-WebAppPool PowerShell cmdlet if IIS is not running.